# Placing a floating info panel

Tags: css, google-apps-script

I'm using Jame Ferreira's Google Script: Enterprise Application Essentials to create a product page (Chapter 5).  I've created the app that displays thumbnails of the products all on a page, and then the info panel with more detail that pops up when the user mouses over. It's using CSS to achieve this styling.

Problem comes in when placing the info panel.  It pops up in only one location, as opposed to being tied to the thumbnail with which it is associated.

Here's the code related to the info panel.  I believe the problem exists in the placement of the last few lines, but have tried everything I can think of:

```
function onInfo(e){
var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
var id = e.parameter.source;
for (var i in productDetails){
if(productDetails[i].id == id){
var r = 50;
var c = 0;
var infoPanel = app.createVerticalPanel().setSize('300px', '300px');
var horzPanel = app.createHorizontalPanel();
var image = app.createImage(productDetails[i].imageUrl).setHeight('100px');
var title = app.createLabel(productDetails[i].title);
horzPanel.add(image);
horzPanel.add(title);
var description = app.createLabel(productDetails[i].description);


infoPanel.add(horzPanel);
infoPanel.add(description);
applyCSS(infoPanel, _infoPanel);
applyCSS(image, _infoImage);
applyCSS(horzPanel, _infoBoxSeparator);
applyCSS(title, _infoTitle);
applyCSS(description, _infoDescription);

app.getElementById('infoGrid').setVisible(true)
.setWidget(0,0, infoPanel);
break;

}
c++
if (c == 3){
c = 0;
r = r+250;
}
switch (c)
{
case 0:
c=250;
break;
case 1:
c=500;
break;
case 2:
c=250;
break;
}
}

var _infoLocation =
{
"top":r+"px",
"left":c+"px",}

applyCSS(infoPanel, _infoLocation);

return app;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may get the position of the mouse using `e.parameter.x` and `e.parameter.y` based on which you can position the infoPanel

```
infoPanel.setStyleAttribute('top',e.parameter.y)
    .setStyleAttribute('left',e.parameter.x).setStyleAttribute('zIndex','1')
    .setStyleAttribute('position','fixed');
```

You may add some offset to x and y positions of mouse to display it according to your needs.

Position related parameter which you get in handler function are

```
e.parameter.x
e.parameter.y

e.parameter.clientX
e.parameter.clientY

e.parameter.screenX
e.parameter.screenY
```

Comment: Much better, but it looks as if, because it's a flextable that the X and Y are being set in relation to the cell.  So, even if I am in column three, if I am all the way to the left of that column, the infopanel appears all the way left.   Here's a the Web App link. https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxnX_v9jhXsQKrMZYII1cYsfW6M_c7UR-OsZmHM2bYAh0cPdQ0/exec

Comment: @MartinK Ah sorry, I didn't try with flexTable. I have updated my answer, Please check it. That may help you

Comment: Thanks for you update! I've tried and tried, but the .client and .screen parameters keep any panel from displaying.  Will keep looking for a solution.  Thanks for you time, and [your very useful site](https://sites.google.com/site/appsscripttutorial/)! It's been invaluable to me as I find my way through GAS.